# experience with using SS on Windows 2016 MSCS VMware Virtual machines

Tags: vmware-esx, windows-server-2016, storage-spaces, microsoft-cluster-server

After reading multiple documentations around setting up a MS 2016 Fail-over Cluster with Storage Spaces on VMware ESX it seems that this configuration is not supported but it only says server 2012 and above.

I am looking for people's advice with virtualizing a MSCS File Server with RDMs using Storage spaces on VMware. What are the expected issues or why is this configuration not supported?

Answer (score 5):

You can doesn't mean you should. For shared storage you can stick with shared virtual disks and NOT do any SDS within clustered production VMs: This only brings in an extra level of complexity.

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2147661

Comment: That article doesn't actually say that you can't use Storage Spaces to create a Virtual disk... Essentially I am looking to do something similar to LVM on Linux and have a group of virtual disks that I can manage from a pool.

Answer (score 0):

Any nested virtualization is not supported for production, but can be used for proof of concept. Also, you can create a shared storage between hosts and create a file server inside VM which will be located on shared storage and in such case nested FC is not needed.